# java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\sba\input

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am using [this project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin-samples) as my Spring Batch Admin project.

This UI has a **Files** tab where you can upload files and that is not working on my PC having Windows 8.1.

I get exception - `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\sba\input`

at method - `createFile()` , line 107 (`!new URI(directory.getAbsolutePath())`) for [LocalFileService class](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/admin/service/LocalFileService.java)

I have specified property, `batch.files.upload-dir=/sba/input` as indicated in samples.

Process creates directory - `C:\sba\input` as my Weblogic is deployed in C drive and above admin project deployed in Weblogic.

Do I need to specify this property in some other way for Windows or is it a bug in API?

In API, the bean is defined as below,

```
<bean id="fileService" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.service.LocalFileService"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <property name="fileSender" ref="fileSender" />
        <property name="outputDir" value="${batch.files.upload-dir:#{systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir']}}"/>
    </bean>
```

I get same exception when this property is not specified and system tries to use user's temp directory.

Comment: Windows paths with backslash must be converted to `/` for the URI format.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci: That is API code, I guess I can't make changes there. Seems, all I can do is to provide property in appropriate format ( if there exists a value for which that code can work ).